# How do I delete one image from another for transparent background in Illustrator 2019?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created this image and would like to to be able to have a transparent outline of the state (filament) for one-color applications. The bulb part has a black fill. Any suggestions on how I can "delete" the state outline?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this (the image here is just a rough edit):

[image]

Now, if that's your problem, here's the solution:

Basically you subtract one shape from another. You can do it with *Windows > Pathfinder* tool. You have to use **Minus Front** option from there.

**How to use Minus Front:**

1. The shape you want to subtract from another, must be above it. So here, your filament shape should be on Bulb shape.
2. After that **select both of the shapes** *(nothing else should be selected. E.g., if your bulb is a part of a group that contains some other shape(s), either use direct selection tool to select bulb only, or ungroup it first)*
3. Click **Minus Front** and you're done.

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I wasn't  grabbing the bottom layer, just the top. Thanks!

Comment: @Jenna please mark this answer accepted if that solved your problem.